# Effect of temperature on Photoelectric Effect?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect

Does temperature of emitter plate have any effect on stopping potential if intensity and frequency of incident radiation and potential difference b/w collector and emitter plate remains same? (and also same material)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small [effect of temperature on the work function  of metals](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4608/9/7/016/pdf), i.e., the energy you need to remove an electron into vacuum. This is mainly due to the thermal expansion of the crystal lattice.  Thus for the same light frequency, the kinetic energy of the emitted electrons, and thus the stopping potential,  will depend very weakly on the temperature of the emitting metal plate.

Comment: Also due to thermalisation of electrons to higher states from which they can be emitted.